# PROLOG Finite automata compile error

Tags: prolog, finite-automata, state-machine

I need help with my Prolog homework.

So I have to represent a finite automata with 4 states. It is a simple laughing automata. But i don't know why I get this error:

```
Warning: c:/users/joanpc/desktop/p1_ex2.pl:20:
    Singleton variables: [Current]
Warning: c:/users/joanpc/desktop/p1_ex2.pl:32:
    Singleton variables: [ListNodes]
ERROR: c:/users/joanpc/desktop/p1_ex2.pl:32:
    No permission to modify static procedure `(=)/2'
```

I think that it is some kind of syntax error but I can't recognise it. Here is my code:

```
recognize(X) :-
  init(ListNodes, Y),
  process(X, Y).

process([X|Rest], Node) :-
  NextNode is (Node+1),
  arc(Node, NextNode, X),
  process(Rest, NextNode).

process(X, Node) :- final(Node).

process([X|Rest], Node) :-
  NextNode is (Node-1),
  arc(Node, NextNode, X),
  process(Rest, NextNode).

init(Current, Y) :-
  initial(Current),
  Y = Current.
init([Current|Rest]) :- init(Rest).

%Facts

initial(1).
final(4).

arc(1,2, j).
arc(2,1, a).
arc(2,3, a).
arc(3,4, !).

ListNodes = [1,2,3,4].
```

I am new with Prolog so any help will be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: `init([Current|Rest])` - what happens to `Current`? `ListNodes =` - the equal sign is the predicate name here, which is probably not what you intended.

Comment: Prolog isn't like other languages. So asserting `ListNodes = [1,2,3,4].` doesn't assign `[1,2,3,4]` to `ListNodes` as some kind of global or static variable. What it does is attempt to redefine Prolog's built-in `(=)/2` operator by asserting `=(ListNodes, [1,2,3,4]).`. What is it you expect to achieve with this statement?

Comment: You are using `init(Current, Y)` and `init([Current|Rest])` with different arities for starters. init/1 is not equal to init/2, so this the above will never get called successfully if you call `init(Current, Y)` with a List. Use `init([Current|_], initial(Current))` instead. You also never use `Current` in `init([Current|Rest])`, so it's marked as a singleton which is never used and then discarded. Replace such variables with anonymous `_` variables instead, giving you `init([_|Rest], Result) :- init(Rest, Result).` instead.